# json_encode will not encode more than 6670 rows

Tags: php, json

Someone else had this issue back in '07, but it was not answered:  in PHP, json_encode($someArray) silently fails (returns null) if the array has more than 6,670 rows.  Does someone have a workaround.  Limiting the size of the array to 6600, for example produces the expected result.  I can do some do multiple json calls with partial arrays and concatenate results, but that involves some funky string manipulation to get them to stitch together properly, and I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example of php code that demonstrates how and when this happens?

Comment: Have you tried increasing PHP's memory limit?

Comment: Did you check max depth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly depends on your PHP version and the memory allowed for use by PHP (and possibly the actual size of all the data in the array, too).
What you could do if all else fails, is this:
Write a function that checks the size of a given array, then split off a smaller part that will encode, then keep doing this until all parts are encoded, then join them again. If this is the route you end up taking, post a comment on this answer, and perhaps I can help you out with it. (This is based on the answer by Nytrix)
EDIT, example below:

```
function encodeArray($array, $threshold = 6670) {
    $json = array();
    while (count($array) > 0) {
        $partial_array = array_slice($array, 0, $threshold);
        $json[] = ltrim(rtrim(json_encode($partial_array), "]"), "[");
        $array = array_slice($array, $threshold);
    }

    $json = '[' . implode(',', $json) . ']';
    return $json;
}
```

Comment: Cheers! Though I think the choice for a for loop instead of my while-whack is a bit better still. Counting passes in a while loop just feels dirty I guess ^^

Comment: Short and sweet.  I like it.  I haven't tested this yet, but I think it may omit the comma between 'chunks'.  (If so, easy fix)  Thanks again.

Comment: I've now actually tested this code, it doesn't throw out valid `json` nor anything else... test it [**here**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/58cecc502255d0800d742bf9e02e65208b73d47b) online

Comment: Nytrix was right, there were some bugs introduced in previous edits. Fixed them, as visible here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/68b391ab396e76b8942efb04bc23c5489a20760a

Answer (score 3):

You could always just first `slice` the array into 2 parts (assuming it's not bigger then 2 times those rows). After that encode it, and add them together again. In case that isn't a solution, you need to increase your memory limit.

Here is an example, test it [**here**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6a61415d952107589e7cef4d7c1ce90abf80295a). On @GeertvanDijk suggestion, I made this a flexible function, in order to increase functionality!

```
<?php
  $bigarray = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

function json_encode_big($bigarray,$split_over = 6670){
  $parts = ceil((count($bigarray) / $split_over));

  $start = 0;
  $end = $split_over;

  $jsoneconded = [];

  for($part = 0; $part < $parts; $part++){
    $half1 = array_slice($bigarray,$start,$end);
    $name = "json".$part;
    $$name = ltrim(rtrim(json_encode($half1),"]"),"[");
    $jsoneconded[] = $$name;
    $start += $split_over;
  }

  return "[".implode($jsoneconded,",")."]";
}

print_r(json_encode_big($bigarray));
?>
```

I have now test this with more rows then 6,670. You can test it online [**here**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7fa54374be061434fb486f783d59e3ea63021abf) as well.

Now, I have to mention that I tested the normal `json_encode()` with a million rows, no problem. Yet, I still hope this solves your problem...

---

In case that you run out of memory, you can set the `memory_limit` to a higher value. I would advice against this, instead I would retrieve the data in parts, and procces those in parts. As I don't know how you retrieve this data, I can't give an example how to regulate that.  Here is how you change the memory in case you need to (sometimes it is the only option, and still "good").

```
ini_set("memory_limit","256M");
```

In this case, it is the dubbel from the *default*, you can see that it is `128M` in [this documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.resource-limits)